# Yii2 Highcharts syntax in function

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, yii2

I want to add an image to the legend of a pie in Highcharts Yii2. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/18nx7yus) but I cannot write it into my PHP widget in the `labelFormat` section.

```
<? = \dosamigos\highcharts\HighCharts::widget([
  'clientOptions' => [
    'chart' => [
      'type' => 'pie'
    ],
    'legend' => [
      'useHTML' => TRUE,
      'labelFormatter' => "function () {
        return '<img src='http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png'/>' + this.name;
      }",
      'itemMarginBottom' => 5
    ],
    ...
?>
```

Comment: see your js console, if any error there

Comment: no errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be:

```
'legend' => [
  'useHTML' => TRUE,
  'labelFormatter' => new JsExpression('function () { return \"<img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png"/>\" + this.name; }'),
  'itemMarginBottom' => 5
],
```

According to the first tip from [here](https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts#tips).